# How to insert the raw content raw of an xml file to an aspx page ? Is it malpractice to do so?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I add the content of a XML file directly into a aspx file (with its aspx.cs code-behind) ? **Is it malpractice to do so** ?

Context: I need to generate a drop-down navbar-menu corresponding to an XML config file (in which every item names are defined). I have already coded a long and counter-intuitive implantation using asp.NET libraries (based on the “HorizontalMenu“ object) : but the result is suboptimal both in pure code and accessibility. I am indeed working on a project that **bans callbacks** and therefore miss many functionalities that I could only implement though informal workaround (such as hard-coding javascripts call into menutitem-links in order to retrieve selected item).

My idea would be to redo everything and code my navbar by hand: I am inspiring myself from this implementation: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar

Having the XML config file already formatted in HTML for the implementation of the navbar would simplify the project. I would then simply need to copy its content inside my aspx file though code behind (and then figure out a way to add the java-scripts triggers: but that's not the point of this question).

Here is a summed simplified example of what I have in mind: 
XML file: navbar_config.xml

```
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

aspx file: mainpage.aspx

```
    <body>
      <%= navbar_config %>
      (…)
    </body>
```

Aspx.cs file: mainpage.aspx.cs

```
private string navbar_config {get{ return ???}} //this should return the content of the xml
```

EDIT: note that in the context of my project, the navbar is basically a glorified select (its links are not links, just selectable items used as variables in other part of the page).

Comment: XML is not a UI markup language, all though HTML5 can be formatted as XML-compliant text in some cases. Correct me if I am wrong, but it looks like your end goal is to populate the links in the div with the class "dropdown-content", correct?

Comment: @Mike Marshall Basically yes. That is what I have done in my previous attempt using HorizontalMenu, I was iterating though the XML file and only selecting the information required. But know that I am taking a different approach, I was wondering If I could simply copy paste a correctly formatted chunk of text into the code. But then again, I wonder if that's not a malpractice: less and simplier code, but no clear trace of the structure outside the xml conf file...